# Why does make behave strangely when rule has multiple targets with the % character?

Tags: make, gnu-make

According to [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets)

> A rule with multiple targets is equivalent to writing many rules, each with one target, and all identical aside from that. The same recipe applies to all the targets, but its effect may vary because you can substitute the actual target name into the recipe using ‘$@’. The rule contributes the same prerequisites to all the targets also.

###### First Makefile:

```
%.in %.out:
    echo BLANK > $@
```

Corresponding bash session:

```
$ ls
Makefile

$ make a.in a.out
echo BLANK > a.in
make: Nothing to be done for 'a.out'.

$ ls
Makefile  a.in

$ make a.out
echo BLANK > a.out

$ ls
Makefile  a.in  a.out

$ make b.in c.out
echo BLANK > b.in
echo BLANK > c.out

$ make d.in d.out
echo BLANK > d.in
make: Nothing to be done for 'd.out'.

$ make e.out e.in
echo BLANK > e.out
make: Nothing to be done for 'e.in'.

$ ls
Makefile  a.in  a.out  b.in  c.out  d.in  e.out
```

###### Second Makefile:

```
%.in:
    echo BLANK > $@

%.out:
    echo BLANK > $@
```

Corresponding bash session:

```
$ ls
Makefile

$ make a.in a.out
echo BLANK > a.in
echo BLANK > a.out

$ ls
Makefile  a.in  a.out

$ # nice
```

##### So, the question:

Why doesn't the first Makefile create targets like `<name>.in <same name>.out` simultaneously? Why isn't it interpreted similar to the second Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules tell `make` that a single invocation of the recipe will create *both* the `.in` and `.out` targets.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html explains this. It says (in the penultimate paragraph):

> "Pattern rules may have more than one target; however, every target must  contain a % character. Multiple target patterns in pattern rules are always treated as grouped targets (see Multiple Targets in a Rule) regardless of whether they use the : or &: separator. "

If you then follow the link to [Multiple Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html) it explains that grouped targets (normally using the `&:` separator when you have explicit rules) tell `make` that a single invocation of the recipe will create *all* of them, not just one at a time.

So your pattern rule is the equivalent of this:

```
a.in a.out &:
        echo BLANK > $@
```

... and not the equivalent of this as you intended:

```
a.in a.out :
        echo BLANK > $@
```

As far as I know, there's no way to make a pattern rule which works like the latter and creates just one at a time. You just have to have *separate* rules for `%.in` and `%.out`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supposed to have multiple implicit targets in a single rule.  I don't remember if this is stated anywhere, but rules like that are certainly bad practice.  Here's what's going on:

```
$ cat Makefile 
%.in %.out :
        echo BLANK > $@

$ make -d a.in a.out
[... irrelevant output skipped ...]
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'a.in'.
 File 'a.in' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'a.in'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem 'a'.
 Found an implicit rule for 'a.in'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'a.in'.
Must remake target 'a.in'.
echo BLANK > a.in
Successfully remade target file 'a.in'.
Considering target file 'a.out'.
File 'a.out' was considered already.
make: Nothing to be done for 'a.out'.
```

Note the lines:

```
Considering target file 'a.out'.
File 'a.out' was considered already.
```

Implicit targets don't "exist" until they get to be tried, and thus the rule doesn't get "split" into multiple rules.  When `a.in` is tried and matched successfully all other targets are marked as tried.  The vast majority of time this is not what you want.  Just write two rules.

Comment: Why are rules like that certainly bad practice? I just want to have the same recipe for all files that match pattern `*.{in,out}`. Isn't writing two rules with same recipes bad practice?

Comment: > _When a.in is tried and matched successfully all other targets are marked as tried._ < Is it a bug?

Comment: @belkka _Why are rules like that certainly bad practice?_ - Because they don't work the way you expect? As an end user you don't really get to make the rules of the tools you're using.  Most of the time you don't even get to choose your tools.  The best you can do is learn to avoid their quirks.

Comment: "_When a.in is tried and matched successfully all other targets are marked as tried._"
I still don't understand, is it a bug or itended behaviour? If it is intended behaviour, were can I read about this? When I use rule with several **explicit** targets (`a.in a.out:`) make works as I expect -- when a.in is tried and matched successfully all other targets **are not** market as tried (?)

Comment: @Sato "_Because they don't work the way you expect..._" I used to think that you had in mind "It is known to be a bad style of writing makefiles" when wrote "rules like that are certainly bad practice" :)

Comment: Well, I "knew" `%.in %.out:` is a bad idea, but I don't remember where or how I found that out. `%` is a GNU extension, there is no such thing in BSD `make`, so there isn't anything to compare against to tell whether this behaviour is intentional or not.  Implicit targets _are_ different from explicit ones, since you can't have something like `%.in a.out:`, which is why I'd go with intentional. IIRC this behaviour is also quite old (but then I haven't been using GNU `make` much). I suppose you could ask the developers.